# What is $\alpha \sin(\theta) + \beta \frac{d \theta}{d t}$ in the inverted pendulum problem?

Tags: control, stability, machine-learning

I am preparing for an exam in neural networks. As an example for self-organizing maps they showed the inverted pendulum problem where you want to keep the pole vertical:

[image]

Now the part which I don't understand:

> $$f(\theta) = \alpha \sin(\theta) + \beta \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}$$
>   Let $x= \theta$, $y=\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}$, $z=f$.
>
> Solution with SOM:
>
> - three-dimensional surface in $(x,y,z)$
> - adapt two-dimensional SOM to surface
> - Method of control
>
>   - For a given $(x,y)$ find neuron $k$ for wich $w_k = [w_{k1}, w_{k2}, w_{k2}, w_{k3}]$
>   - $f(\theta)$ is then $w_{k3}$

I guess we use the SOM to learn the function $f$. However, I would like to understand where $f$ comes from / what it means in this model.

Comment: Do you know the equations of motion for the inverted pendulum problem.  I think that will give you a good indication as to where the function f comes from.

Answer (score 8):

The function $f$ comes from the equation of motion for the inverted pendulum problem (*inverted pendulum alone*, not including the motion of the wheeled platform). If you consider your figure but ignore the side-to-side motion of the cart, then the equilibrium of moments about the hinge is:

$\sum M = m g l \sin \theta - b\frac{d \theta}{dt} $

Where $m$ is the mass of the black point mass at the tip of the pendulum and $b$ is the linear damping coefficient (due to friction at the hinge).

The sum of moments is equal to the inertial reaction (equivalent of $F = ma$):

$\sum M = m l^2 \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}$

Equating these two leads to the equation of motion for the inverted pendulum:

$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \frac{g}{l} \sin \theta - \frac{b}{m l^2} \frac{d \theta}{dt}$

Substituting $\alpha = \frac{g}{l}$ and $\beta = -\frac{b}{m l^2}$, we then recover the form of the function $f$ in your question:

$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \alpha \sin \theta + \beta \frac{d \theta}{dt}$

(It should again be stressed that this analysis does not include the side-to-side motion of the cart.)